# Dynamics 365 SDK throws exception "The Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) negotiation failed"

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I'm connecting to a Dynamics 365 v9.0 on-premises organization across Active Directory domains through the `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk` + `Microsoft.Pfe.Xrm.Core` NuGet packages to trigger SDK requests. Sometimes I get an exception back: `The Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) negotiation failed`.

My machine and the Dynamics server are located in different domains. Fiddler traces show that both machines are accessible in the network.

The exception is thrown in the PFE lib, more specifically the `operation()` line below.

```cs
Parallel.ForEach<TRequest, ParallelOrganizationOperationContext<TRequest, bool>>(requests,
    new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = this.MaxDegreeOfParallelism },
    () => new ParallelOrganizationOperationContext<TRequest, bool>(),
    (request, loopState, index, context) =>
    {
        try
        {
            operation(request, threadLocalProxy.Value);
        }
        catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> fault)
        {
            //Track faults locally                                
            if (errorHandler != null)
            {
                context.Failures.Add(new ParallelOrganizationOperationFailure<TRequest>(request, fault));
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return context;
    },
    (context) =>
    {
        //Join faults together
        Array.ForEach(context.Failures.ToArray(), f => allFailures.Add(f));
    });
```

Source: https://github.com/seanmcne/XrmCoreLibrary/blob/8892a9e93c42d8c35aac2a212588d45359cfd1a2/v8/Client/ParallelServiceProxy.cs#L236

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sandrino Di Mattia provided with a workaround in the [Early binding tips and tricks for Dynamics CRM 2011](http://sandrinodimattia.net/early-binding-tips-and-tricks-for-dynamics-crm-2011/) article:

> If you’re working with a virtual machine that is part of an other domain you might get this error (cross domain call). To solve this you’ll need to change the way you pass the authentication arguments to CrmSvcUtil.exe Instead of calling CrmSvcUtil.exe using the following line:
>
> ```
>     CrmSvcUtil.exe /url:"http:/srv/org/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc" /out:Context.cs
>     /username:"sandrino" /password:"pass" /domain:"somedomain" /serviceContextName:Context
> ```
>
> Change it to the following:
>
> ```
>     CrmSvcUtil.exe /url:"http:/srv/org/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc" /out:Context.cs
>     /username:"sandrino@somedomain" /password:"pass" /serviceContextName:Context
> ```
>
> By removing the domain argument and appending the domain to the username (separated with the @ sign) you’ll solve the cross domain problem.